# Sql help in trying to get a row of data with the lowest value in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query so far:

```
SELECT `p`.`id`, cp.pattern_category_id, `p`.`title`, `p`.`filename`, p.precedence
     FROM (`patterns` p) JOIN `categories_to_patterns` cp ON `p`.`id` = `cp`.`pattern_id` 
     JOIN `pattern_categories` pc ON `cp`.`pattern_category_id` = `pc`.`id` 
     WHERE `cp`.`pattern_category_id` = '29'
```

Which returns this:

```
id | pattern_category_id | title | filename | precedence
6             29           Alan     alan.jpg      2
7             29           Joe      joe.jpg       1
```

What I want to do is get the row that has the lowest precedence. I'm not sure if i should be using a subquery, doing a min(p.precedence) with some group by's, or using group by/having.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always `ORDER BY p.precedence ASC limit 1` does that work for you?

Comment: Or, you could have `WHERE precedence = (SELECT MIN(precedence) FROM ...)`, which would be able to return more than one row with the same (minimal) precedence.

Comment: Nice answer. I only need it to return 1 row. Works like a charm.